# Error de sintaxis "'."al guardar string url en SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un controlador como el siguiente, cuyo propósito es recibir dos valores string y actualizar en la base:

```
    [Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]
public static bool UpdateMailsProcessStatus(string codeaction, string urlGuid)
{

    DBLayer db = new DBLayer();
    try
    {
        db.Execute(string.Format("exec dbo.WEB_UpdateSendMailStatus '{0}',{1}", codeaction, urlGuid));

        db.Dispose();
        db.CloseConnection();
        db = null;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        db.Dispose();
        db.CloseConnection();
        db = null;

        return false;
    }
}
```

y tengo un store que recibe dichos parametros así...

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WEB_UpdateSendMailStatus] (@codeaction VARCHAR(MAX) ,  @urlGuid VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Los valores que recibe son similares a estos:

```
codeaction = "12345"
urlGuid = "http://localhost/Pages/pagina.aspx?exp=4365436-bnert346-45g4hn"
```

Sin embargo arroja la siguiente excepcion:

*"incorrect syntax near 'http'."*

Cúal sería el problema?, si intento insertarlos manualmente en la base cambiando las comillas " por ' funciona.

Comment: no te faltan las comillas alrededor del parametro 1?

Comment: Creo que @blanchi tiene razón.  Que pasa con "exec dbo.WEB_UpdateSendMailStatus '{0}','{1}'" ?

Comment: Les agradezco su ayuda, pude resolverlo cambiando el modo de ejecución. El String.Format agregaba "" demás , es decir quedaba ""string""

Comment: @Citrusl pon tu solución como respuesta, abajo en "Tu Respuesta". Luego, incluso, puedes marcarla como respuesta aceptada para que otros sepan cómo se resuelve este problema.

Answer (score 0):

No debería formatear a String un valor que ya es String:

```
db.Execute(string.Format("exec dbo.WEB_UpdateSendMailStatus '{0}',{1}", codeaction, urlGuid));
```

De esta manera funciona:

```
   string connectionStringOut = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseName"]);
    string procedureOut = "dbo.WEB_UpdateSendMailStatus";

    using (SqlConnection conOut = new SqlConnection(connectionStringOut))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmdOut = new SqlCommand(procedureOut, conOut))
        {
            cmdOut.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdOut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeaction", codeaction);
            cmdOut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urlGuid", urlGuid);
            try
            {
                conOut.Open();
                cmdOut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conOut.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                conOut.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```